# Why error Cannot read property 'addEventListener' is showing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use this function:

```
<div id="one">
<div class="options-parameters-input">
gfdgd
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>

var DN = document.getElementById("DN");
DN.addEventListener("keyup",both);

function both(){
document.getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0].style.fontSize = this.value+'px';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/89/

But when I move this code to my phpBB custom theme, then i get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null(…)

why ?

also my javacript files are called from footer.

I dont know what I need to do, I hope you can help me.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe because you have multiple elements that has an ID of DN but based on error. Element #DN cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please check below code perfectly run.

<div id="one">
<div class="options-parameters-input">
Example
</div>
</div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script>
var DN = document.getElementById("DN");
DN.addEventListener("keyup",both);

function both(){
document.getElementsByClassName("options-parameters-input")[0].style.fontSize = this.value+'px';
}

</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```